# How assign EF table data to List

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, model

I need to get the specific raw column value from the table. I write the code as follows,

```
public List<MessageTemplateDto> GetMessageTemplate(int tenantId,NotifyVia notifyVia,string notifyEvent)
{

    ClientContext context = clientContextFactory.GetContext(tenantId);
    List<MessageTemplateDto> msgTemplate = new List<MessageTemplateDto>();
    var xx = context.MessageTemplates.Where(m => m.NotifyEvent == notifyEvent && m.SendVia == notifyVia.ToString()).ToList();
    msgTemplate.Add(xx);
    return msgTemplate;
}
```

But above code gives this error,

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Kronos.FMSI.LT.EFModel.ClientData.MessageTemplate>' to 'Kronos.FMSI.LT.Api.Interface.Models.Notification.MessageTemplateDto'
```

my DTO class as follows,

```
public class MessageTemplateDto
{
    public int TemplateID { get; set; }
    public string NotifyEvent { get; set; }
    public string SendVia { get; set; }
    public string Template { get; set; }
}
```

What I did wrong here? as I previously mentioned I need to get one column value from the raw(`Template` value). Do I need to write return type as `List<MessageTemplateDto>` ? If I use return type as string, is it not a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .Select() to create a new MessageTemplateDto and set each property you want to populate:

```
return context.MessageTemplates
  .Where(m => m.NotifyEvent == notifyEvent && m.SendVia == notifyVia.ToString())
  .Select(r => new MessageTemplateDto() {
      TemplateID = r.WhateverTheColumnNameForIdIsInYourMapping,
      r.NotifyEvent //both column and dto property have same name so this can be simplified
      r.SendVia //again, both dto and column seem to have the same name so this can simply be this
      Template = r.WhateverYourColumnNameForTemplateIsInTheContext 
    }
  .ToList();
```

Etc

Inside the select the r represents the table row as delivered by the context so the column names in r will be whatever you set up in your mapping. You didn't show the mappin so I couldn't tell what some of your column names are

This isn't the only way to do throw, you can do things like provide a constructor in the Dto that takes an object of type that represents the entity, and then set the properties in the constructor. This is typically less often done because it binds your Dto suite of objects to be dependent on your entity domain and they should probably be separate. You can create a Map method in your repository class that is running this query; map takes a db entity and returns a dto; it depends how many times you'll do this - if this is the only place you'll ever query this table and create a list of template dto there's no point making a mapping method for it.

Ultimately the original problem was that your original query was returning a list of db entity objects and they cannot be directly assigned to a list declared to only have a list of dto objects because they're different objects. Like assigning a list of car type objects to a list - instead you have to use Select to generate a Dto from the data entity. Dto are typically different, lighter, fewer properties, maybe some calculated properties that aren't in the db (like the dto has Age, the db has bitthdaye) and are used to move a small amount of data to some other place, perhaps even over a network hence why they're smaller

Comment: Can please tell me a answer for my second question? do I need to return whole model to take one value? can't I use string as return type?

Comment: and I changed the code as your answer, Still have same error

Comment: changed the code as this and error gone . `List<MessageTemplateDto> msgTemplate = context.MessageTemplates.Where(m => m.NotifyEvent == notifyEvent && m.SendVia == notifyVia.ToString()).Select(r => new MessageTemplateDto() { Template = r.Template }).ToList();`

Comment: You either need to use addrange or just use the response from the query as your list

Comment: Yep that's it.. or you can just return the query result directly- see my edit

Comment: Do I need write a code to take one value from the table? is this good code or bad?

Comment: Well, it's not bad per se.. if you fill it out with the other stuff then you could reuse it in other places where you need mother data from the table- that would be good! :) but the calling class already knows the Via and the event, so if it doesn't care about the template Id then sure you could make it return a list of string. You'll still need a select but it will look more like `.Select(r=>r.Template)`

Comment: I sir please tell me, how can I access template value from returned list, I called it as `List<MessageTemplateDto> messageTemplateDtos = messageStore.GetMessageTemplate(tenantId,via,notifyEvent);` So how can I get  onlyTemplate value? from the list

Comment: Depends which one you want :) if you want the first one then it's `messageTemplateDtos[0].Template` - index your list like an array and pull the .Template out. Might be wise to check your list even has a first one because it could be completely empty in which case you'll get an index out of range exception